# Inserting EditText & Spinner data to SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to figure out how to capture data from a form using EditText & Spinner's and insert it into a SQLite database.  I am able to write the hard coded attributes but when I try to use R.id.fieldName it throws an error due to being an Integer vice a String.

```
public class PetAdd extends Activity {
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
private OnClickListener btnPetAddListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        db.open();
        long id;
        id = db.insertPet("name", "type", "breed", "sex", "notes");
         /**id = db.insertPet(R.id.petName, R.id.SpinnerPetType, R.id.petBreed, R.id.SpinnerPetGender, R.id.EditTextPetAddOptions);*/
        db.close();
    }
};
```

I'm still trying to learn all this stuff and my brain is fried from looking at a plethora of online tutorials, examples and Google documentation.  If anyone can show me how to do this or direct me to a barney style tutorial that breaks it down for me to understand what's going on, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R.id.fieldName is a numeric reference to the item in your Activity (provided it's part of your layout).

You'll need to call findViewById(R.id.fieldName) to get a refererene to it. You'll also need to cast it to the correct type of view (in your case EditText)  and then call getText().toString() on the whole thing.

Putting it all together...

```
EditText myField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName); //assuming you have a field named userName in your XML

String userNameValue = myField.getText().toString();
```

Oh, and welcome to Stack... don't forget to mark answers as correct and up-vote them when they're helpful.

Comment: Awesome, that did it for me.  Within seconds, I was able to implement this and get me back on track.  Thanks!  About to start trying to figure out the spinner thing sfratini is talking about down below with the getitem, getitemid stuff.

Comment: you're most welcome. The spinner is a bit more tricky, you should refer to a good online reference of how to interact with it. Like this one for instance: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1517

Comment: Actually, got it working with the same setup as above, just used Spinner (Spinner) vice EditText (EditText).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use R.id.name you are in fact using internally generated int that Android uses. You need the raw data your spinner has.

I suggest you play with getItem and getItemId in your Spinner. If you are using a SimpleAdapter you can expect to get the ID of your item with getItemId.

The implementation of getItem is up to you. I usually use BaseAdapter or in the case of Spinners, ArrayAdapter, which has several convenient methods.

And with the EditText you need to call getText() to the EditText.